# У тех, кто считают меня виноватой. Или считает?

Tags: грамотная-речь, согласование, единственное-множественное-число

*Не могу просить прощения **у тех, кто** несправедливо **считают** меня виноватой...*
Как правильно?

Comment: Можете мне, пожалуйста, срочно подсказать? Очень хочу и очень надо!

Comment: Катюша, приветствую Вас на форуме! Предложение, в том числе и заголовок, принято начинать с прописной (или большой) буквы. Сейчас подправлю, как надо, — всё будет красиво и правильно.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо большое, Римма Михайловна!

Comment: Здравствуйте, Катюша! Будьте внимательны. Я уже один раз *так* шутила. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16ntKyItv7M) Римма Михайлова я. P. S. Пожалуй, поддержу Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В "Справочнике по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию" указано (§ 187) следующее:

> При подлежащем – относительном местоимении *кто* (в функции союзного
> слова в придаточном предложении) сказуемое может стоять **как в форме
> единственного, так и в форме множественного числа**, например:
>
> а)      Все, кто не потерял еще головы, были против (Сергеев-Ценский);
> ...Те, кто не успел к двери, кинулись в радостной панике к окнам
> (Макаренко);
>
> б)      Тут эти люди, кто по неразумию своему малодушно положили
> оружие, узнали стыд... (А.Н. Толстой); В полку служат теперь те, кто
> десять лет назад были пионерами, бегали в школу, играли в снежки (Б.
> Полевой).
>
> Форма множественного числа, возможная при условии, что в главном
> предложении соотносительное слово и сказуемое тоже стоят во
> множественном числе, подчеркивает множественность производителей
> действия. Ср. разные формы согласования в одном и том же сложном
> предложении: Все, кто мог ехать, ехали сами собой; те, кто
> остановились, решали сами с собой, что им надо было делать (Л.
> Толстой).